# How to delete data efficiently without time consume in my sql

Tags: mysql

I want to delete data from **table_a**, using the query below, but it is very slow.
**table_a** contains 21000 data.

```
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id IN (
    SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(N.id) 
    FROM table_a N 
    INNER JOIN table_b E ON N.form_id=E.form_id AND N.element_id=E.element_id  
    WHERE N.option_value=0  
    AND E.element_type IN('checkbox','radio','select')
)
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subselect. You can directly refer to the table you want to delete from in your statement like this:

```
DELETE N
FROM table_a N 
INNER JOIN table_b E ON N.form_id = E.form_id 
                     AND N.element_id = E.element_id 
                     AND E.element_type IN('checkbox','radio','select')
WHERE N.option_value = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. table_a contains 21 crores of data and table_b contains 8 lacks of data. is the above query take much time? or can you guess the time?

Comment: No, I can not guess the time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. i have executed the query. Let me see the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative to juergen_d's answer, you can also create > insert > rename > drop.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_source_table LIKE source_table; -- indeces are copied

INSERT INTO temp_source_table SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE <conditions>; 
-- you SELECT which data you want to save instead of delete

-- maybe do some checks and balances before continuing with ...
RENAME TABLE source_table TO origin_source_table, temp_source_table TO source_table;
DROP TABLE origin_source_table;
```

Of course this depends on the usecase of the table in question, but on tables with large amounts of data and/or complex indeces (don't know the tipping point) this could be a faster option.

This would result in:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table_a LIKE table_a; -- indeces are copied

INSERT INTO temp_table_a
SELECT N.*
FROM table_a N
    LEFT JOIN -- because you select what you want to save
    table_b E ON 
    N.form_id = E.form_id AND N.element_id = E.element_id
WHERE 
    NOT(N.option_value = 0 AND E.element_type IN('checkbox', 'radio', 'select')); 
-- you select which data you want to save instead of delete
-- check/tweak the result of the select before using it as part of the insert

-- maybe do some automatic checks on temp_table_a before continuing with:
RENAME TABLE table_a TO origin_table_a, temp_table_a TO table_a;
DROP TABLE origin_table_a;
```

Comment: I have created new query using your definition, is given below. CREATE TABLE temp_source_table LIKE table_a; -- indeces are copied

INSERT INTO temp_source_table SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id in(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(N.id) FROM  table_a N 
    INNER JOIN table_b E ON N.form_id=E.form_id and N.element_id=E.element_id 
    WHERE N.option_value=0 AND E.element_type IN('checkbox','radio','select'));

Comment: is it ok? or can you correct

Comment: No ... you need to select what data you want to save instead of the data you want to delete. And check the result of every step before executing the DROP ;)